# Popup has weird behavior when content is not visible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have created a custom dropdown in jetpack compose. It works quite well until I minimize it. I have a simple button that switches the state of the dropdown when pressed and then the dropdown itself that is created with the popup component.

The problem is that the popup for some reason has something weird as it's content when I set the `state` to `true` and then `false` again. Theoretically the popup shouldn't be visible since the contents aren't(or at least shouldn't in my understanding) be visible as well.

Here is the code for the popup with the options.

```
    Column{
        Popup{
            if(state){
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(10))
                ){
                    contents()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`state` is the state of the dropdown, (whether it is expanded or not) and then `contents()` is the contents of the popup(some button with the options of the dropdown).

Here is what the dropdown looks like when it is minimized:

[image: dropdown minimized]

Here is what it looks like when it is expanded(set the `state` to `true`):

[image]

And here is what it looks like when I minimize it(set the `state` to `false`):

[image]

I tried to invert the `Popup` and `if` lines and it works as expected, but I also want to animate the contents in the future so the state flag has to be checked inside the popup since the popup itself cannot be animated. This code works for me:

```
    Column{
        if(state){
            Popup{
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(10))
                ){
                    contents()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```